# Input UI elements focus color issues (appcompat 21)

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview, android-appcompat

I updated appcompat to version 21 and notice interesing style behaviour of input elements. E.g. in my app I have `EditText` and `AutoCompleteTextView`. First has `primaryColor` focus color:
[image]
but second has old holo focus color (and style):
[image]
All my activities use single theme. I not changed any of this attributes. Also I not styled these elements in xml or code.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/action_bar</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment `appcompat-v7` doesn't support `AutoCompleteTextView` when it comes to material design style for older versions of Android.

From the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html):

> The Theme.AppCompat themes provide material design styles for these
>   widgets:
>
> - EditText
> - Spinner
> - CheckBox
> - RadioButton
> - SwitchCompat
> - CheckedTextView

That's probably why you're facing this issue.